# saving figure with resizing in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, clone, image-resizing

While displaying my plot in matplotlib, I'm also trying to save it as a png using different dimensions.  I'm making a copy of my main figure (print_fig = fig), and then changing the print_fig size (print_fig.set_size_inches(7,3)).  However this applies changes my original fig instead of just print_fig.  Is there any way I can 'clone' a figure object?

My code looks something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_ylabel("y-label")

for i in xrange(5):
    ax.plot(x, i * x, label='$y = %ix$' % i)

ax.legend()
#change dimension of figure for print 
#clone fig displayed
print_fig = fig
print_fig.set_size_inches(7,3)
print_fig.savefig('print_fig.png')
plt.show()
```

this is what my screen looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to save a png in different resolutions, you don't need to resize the figure. You can just control the image size with the `dpi` keyword in `savefig`.

When you call `savefig`, by default it uses the rc `savefig.dpi` (you can check it on your `.matplotlibrc` file, it is typically 100). So if you want to change the resolution of the output file, you just scale the dpi by the amount you want:

```
plt.savefig('myfig100.png', dpi=100)
plt.savefig('myfig50.png', dpi=50)
```

The second one will have half the width and height of the first.

If you want to change the proportions of width/height, then of course this is of no help. What you are doing is the proper way to change the proportions of the figure for saving. But it will change your window, as you see. If you are not plotting anything else after the `show()`, you can do the following:

1. Do your plotting calls
2. Call `show()`
3. Do `fig.set_size_inches(7,3)`
4. Finally do your `savefig()`

This way, and unless you do further changes to your figure, you'll be able to save with the dimensions required and the figure on the screen will not update to those dimensions.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm aware of changing the dpi, however it's the ratio of the hight/width that i'm looking to change.  Why do you think it's a difficult task? actually what i'm having difficulty grasping is why making changes to print_fig, changes the properties of the original fig.

Comment: When you do `print_fig = fig` you are not copying anything, just calling `fig` by another name (a copy by reference). So any change in `print_fig` will change the original `fig`. I updated the answer with more info on the changing of proportions.

Comment: How could one get a real copy of the figure? I am asking, because I use a matplotlib-canvas in a PyQt4-GUI and want to save the figure with different dimensions than the canvas-figure. But if I change the dimension, also the canvas-figure updates. So I am looking for the same thing as the threadopener. I tried copy.copy, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea: some Matplotlib backends do not display anything, if I remember correctly (like the `pdf` backend), so maybe you could [switch to another backend](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.use), change the figure size (which will not be displayed on screen), and save it (and then switch back to the original backend).

I have not tested this idea, though, and the backend switching is still experimental. But it might be worth a try.